# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager vs AFNetworkReachabilityManager - what's the difference?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

So this, code from the docs:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Shared reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
    }];


    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

Produces this output:

```
2014-08-24 19:56:16.522 app[482:60b] Shared reachability: Reachable via WWAN 
2014-08-24 19:56:16.525 app[482:60b] Shared reachability: Reachable via WWAN
```

Replace it with this code:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Shared reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
    }];


[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];


NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thisdomaindoesntexistatall.com"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            NSLog(@"http://thisdomaindoesntexistatall.com reachable: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
        default:
            NSLog(@"http://thisdomaindoesntexistatall.com not reachable: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
            break;
    }
}];

[manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

And I get this output:

```
2014-08-24 20:00:05.091 app[499:60b] http://thisdomaindoesntexistatall.com reachable: Reachable via WWAN 
2014-08-24 20:00:05.092 app[499:60b] http://thisdomaindoesntexistatall.com reachable: Reachable via WWAN 
2014-08-24 20:00:05.094 app[499:60b] http://thisdomaindoesntexistatall.com reachable: Reachable via WWAN 
2014-08-24 20:00:05.095 app[499:60b] http://thisdomaindoesntexistatall.com reachable: Reachable via WWAN
```

This leads to a two part question:

1) What's the point of the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager if it seems to replace its reachability status block with the the sharedManager?

2) This is also confounding considering AFHTTPRequestOperationManager telling me a non-existent URL is reachable which seems to indicate its really only monitoring overall network access and not ratability to a particular endpoint. Or can it monitor the reachability (which might indicate lack of health if not reachable) of a specific URL?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is [look at the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477467/afhttprequestoperationmanager-vs-afnetworkreachabilitymanager-whats-the-diffe), since it's an open source project.

1. `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` has a lot of additional functionality on top of reachability. My guess that's reachability is there for convenience.
2. *Reachability* is actually not concerned whether the particular endpoint is responsive, it's simply there to notify you of the current state of the networking hardware:

> A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an
>   application into the network stack, can leave the local device.
>   Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be
>   received by the host.
>
> [**SCNetworkReachability Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress)

It's somewhat counterintuitive, until you think in terms of the dynamic nature of the networks and the fact that you most likely don't want to ping a service (ie think hundred of thousands of iOS apps pinging your webservices needlessly), and even if you do that's not a guarantee of anything.